# Unable to store values in mongoDb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

My API log:

```
OPTIONS /api/signup 204 14.010 ms - -
req.body { '{"name":"rahul jain","mobile":"343453","email":"inayath@cantern.in","password":"123","cpassword":"123"}': '' }
POST /api/signup 200 9.296 ms - 56
```

I'm making a post request from `angular.js` to `node.js` server and here is my `angular.js` code:

```
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, $state, $http) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: '', 
    mobile:'',
    email:'',
    password:'',
    cpassword:''
  };

  $scope.signup = function() {
    console.log("user",$scope.user);
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup", $scope.user )
        .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
  };
})
```

Here is my `node.js` code:

```
apiRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) { 
  console.log("req",req.body);
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass name and password.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      mobile: req.body.mobile,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      cpassword: req.body.cpassword
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
    });
  }
});
```

I think that `req.body` object having key-value and key is my whole data. Is that correct? Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that user is not saved into database? How looks json object that you are getting in response?

Comment: @Ivan I checked mongodb no value is stored and my API req.body object is : ` { '{"name":"rahul jain","mobile":"343453","email":"inayath@cantern.in","password":"123","cpassword":"123"}': ' ' } `

Comment: What about response object? Do you get something like this in your response from server: {success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'}

Comment: @Ivan it's giving please pass name and password message I think it's because of our req.body object , it's in wrong format.

Comment: Could you show us settings of your express application. At least show us the part where you have setup body-parser

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic thank you man, i got the solution, i just changed the way of sending $http.post request params.